# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm have some VB code here that I need to put into C#

```
Const KEY_ALL_ACCESS As Integer = &H2003F
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE As Integer = &H80000002
```

I've tried the obvious

```
const int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = &H2003F
const int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
```

But it doesnt't work (I assume as they aren't integers)

I'm new to a lot of this stuff but if you could try to help me that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: `&H` is VB syntax, C# would use `0x`

Comment: Replace &H with 0x.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: That is not valid vb6 code.  Integer is a short and trying to assign, for instance,  &H2003F (131,135 decimal) to an integer will result in an overflow error at compile time.  Those two vb6 constants would each need to be declared as a long in order to accept the given value assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal integers are not written this way. Instead of `&H80000002` you write `0x80000002`. That is, hex integers are prefixed with `0x`, not with `&H`.

Comment: Simply changing the &H to 0x isn't enough you end up with a casting error. 0x denotes a uint.